# Starting activities on tab click

Tags: android, tabs

I have 3 tabs which show different content on click. I want them to open certain activities on click. These activities are nothing but database reports which just need to be displayed. I used web view and works fine on emulator with API level 11 but gives an error saying `Web page not found` on my device which is API level 10. Also, The tabs display data only after clicking on other tabs and coming back to the first.
Is there a way I can start the activities directly instead of using web view?

Any help is appreciated.

**xml**:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TabHost 
       android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></TabWidget>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/txtGetFuelInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Get info from Database" />
                <TextView
android:id="@+id/txtGetFuel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

          <WebView
                android:id="@+id/txtMainGetInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Get info from Database"/>
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtGetMain"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/txtSpareGetInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Get info from Database"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtGetspare"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Class** :

```
public class DetailsTabs extends Activity
{
    TabSpec tspec;
    FuelStoredInfo  fuelInfo;
    WebView fuelView,mainView,sparesView;
    TextView tvFuel, tvMain, tvSpares;
    WebSettings fuelSetting, mainSetting, spareSetting;
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailstabs);

        fuelView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.txtGetFuelInfo);
        mainView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.txtMainGetInfo);
        sparesView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.txtSpareGetInfo);

        //tvFuel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalFuelId);
        //tvMain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalmainId);
        //tvSpares = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalspareId);

        fuelInfo = new FuelStoredInfo(this);
        fuelInfo.open();


        TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();

        // Fuel Expense tab
        tspec = th.newTabSpec("Tag 1");

        tspec.setContent(R.id.tabs1);
        tspec.setIndicator("Fuel"+"\n"+"Expense");
        String Data = fuelInfo.getData();
           double fuelTotal  =fuelInfo.getTotalFuel();
        fuelSetting = fuelView.getSettings();
        fuelSetting.setDefaultFontSize(10);
        //tvFuel.setText("Total fuel expense : Rs. "+ String.valueOf(fuelTotal));
        fuelView.loadData(Data,"text/html",null);
        th.addTab(tspec);

        //Maintenance Expense tab
        tspec = th.newTabSpec("Tag 2");
        tspec.setContent(R.id.tabs2);
        tspec.setIndicator("Maintenance"+"\n"+"Expense");
        mainSetting = mainView.getSettings();
        mainSetting.setDefaultFontSize(10);
        String mainData = fuelInfo.getMainData();
        double mainTotal  =fuelInfo.getTotalMain();
        tvMain.setText("Total maintenance expense : Rs. "+ String.valueOf(mainTotal));
        mainView.loadData(mainData,"text/html",null);

        th.addTab(tspec);

        //Spares Expense tab
        tspec = th.newTabSpec("Tag 3");

        tspec.setContent(R.id.tabs3);
        tspec.setIndicator("Spares"+"\n"+"Expense");
        spareSetting = sparesView.getSettings();
        spareSetting.setDefaultFontSize(10);
        String sparesData= fuelInfo.getSpareData();
        double spareTotal = fuelInfo.getTotalSpares();
        tvSpares.setText("Total spares expense : Rs."+ String.valueOf(spareTotal));
        sparesView.loadData(sparesData,"text/html",null);

        th.addTab(tspec);


        fuelInfo.close();



    }

}
```

Comment: Tabhost is depreated so better use fragments.

Answer (score 0):

TabHost is deprecated so why don't you use ActionBar ?

Any way..I think you should use TabHost something like this

```
Resources ressources = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

    // Android tab
    Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Android")
      .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config))
      .setContent(intentAndroid);
```

There is a good tutorial for this [TabHost Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabSpec Spec = null;
    Spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home");
    Spec.setIndicator("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_home));
    Spec.setContent(new Intent(this, MainList.class));
    tabHost.addTab(Spec);

    Spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("recent");
    Spec.setIndicator("Recent", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_recent));
    Spec.setContent(new Intent(this, Recent.class));
    tabHost.addTab(Spec);

    Spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("setting");
    Spec.setIndicator("Setting", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_setting));
    Spec.setContent(new Intent(this, Setting.class));
    tabHost.addTab(Spec);

    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
```